# SyntaxError: Identifier 'Client' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

[i keep getting this error i dont know why how to fix?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ycg.png)

i tried changing the 'Client' name on line 1 by adding an s to it the site worked but the bot didnt work erroring 'Clients' is not a intrector.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As another comment said the reason it doesn't let you use ''Clients'' is because you need the object ''Client''.

The error Is because you have defined Client more than once.

Try with this at the 1st line:

```js
const { Client, Discord, GatewayIntentBits, dkto } =
require('discord.js');
```

And delete the 6th line.

If you have any questions related to discord.js do not hesitate to write to me. I speak Spanish as my first language and English as my second.

Answer (score -1):

You need the object named `{ Client }` and not `{ Clients }` from either `dkto.js` or `discord.js`.

What you could do though is rename it's instance like this :

```
const { Client as DKTOClient, dkto } = require('dkto.js');
```

so you can both use `Client` from `discord.js` and `DKTOClient` from `dkto.js`